# How do I take a list of keys that contains the value of the inputted key in the table in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

Given the following immutable Map("CAT" -> "ET", "BAT" -> "ET", "DIAMOND" -> "AHND", "HAT" -> "ET"), how do I take a list of keys that contains the value of the inputted key in the table in Scala? If inputted key is not in table, return an empty list.

My Attempt:

```
val word = "CAT"
val table = Map("CAT" -> "ET", "BAT" -> "ET", "DIAMOND" -> "AHND", 
"HAT" -> "ET")
if (table.get(find).isDefined) {
    List(table.get(find))
}
```

Input: "CAT"

Output: List("CAT", "BAT", "HAT")

```
//"CAT" has value "ET"

//Return list of keys that contains the value of the inputted key in the table
```

Comment: Updated the question. This is the one that I need help with.

Comment: Updated my answer. You might want to refrain from posting moving targets.

Comment: @Anonymous updated my answer too. Also, I support jwvh in that you should not be changing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.keys.filter(table(_) == table("CAT"))
```

Comment: I am getting a set, not a list.

Comment: Put `.toList` on the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):scala.collection.Map[B]) to perform the filter and the map in one step.

```
val target = "CAT"
val table = Map(
  "CAT" -> "ET", 
  "BAT" -> "ET",
  "DIAMOND" -> "AHND",
  "HAT" -> "ET"
)

table.get(target).map { find =>
  table.collect { case(key, value) if (value == find) => key }
}
// res0: Option[scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String]] = List(CAT, BAT, HAT)
```

If the **Map** does not have any key that matches target, you will get a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution:

```
table.filter {case (_, v) => v.contains(find)}.keys.toList
```